# Using AOS library with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animate-on-scroll

I use AOS (Animate on scroll) library with vue. AOS provides custom JS event: `document.addEventListener('aos:in', ({ detail }) => {
  console.log('animated in', detail);
});`

I would like to fire a function when this event happens.
How do I apply that into my vue component?
It would look like: `v-on-aos:in` using `v-on / @`, but it doesn't work.

This is what I have tried:
`<div v-on:aos:in="myFunction" />`

Comment: did you try `v-on:aos:in="myFunction"`?

Comment: are you sure the event bubbles or can reach the div you want?, maybe it is only listenable on document level and does not propagate to specific elements

Comment: `AOS dispatches two events on document: aos:in and aos:out whenever any element animates in or out, so that you can do extra stuff in JS:` - as author says, and yeah, it works with @click event, the only problem is that `aos:in`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your document event listeners on created method, then pass your vue component method.

```
  created() {
    document.addEventListener('aos:in', this.aosEvent)
  },
   methods: {
    aosEvent(d){
      // event data
      console.log(d);
    }
  }
```